# Default controls for implementing Xcode-like folding option list

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I wish I could implement the same type of control that Xcode has:

[image]

Is it possible with using default storyboards for Cocoa? I want some options to be able to grouped into foldable construction and also that the whole thing will be scrollable.

Is there an easy way to do that or that will involve a lot of coding and auto-layout playing?

Comment: Possibly NSOutlineView, but it might take some heavy customization.

Comment: Download the two files in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/09c8379401ce1925894f1d755b49ccd2) and drop them in a new “Cocoa Application” project for a demo of doing this almost entirely in the storyboard, using `NSStackView`s and Cocoa bindings.

Comment: Ok, I got the most of it myself, really appreciate the help. The only thing I cant solve is how to embed it in scroll view? When I do that and fold option section it sticks to the bottom of the scroll view and not the top like in XCode, also post it as an answer, I will accept that